# Как увеличить на 1 значение в DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Имеется таблица DataGridView. Каждая ее строка должна быть уникальной, если же происходит попытка добавления уже существующей строки, то значение в столбце "Количество" нужно увеличить на 1.

Как это сделать?

*DataGridView[x, y].Value* есть тип *object*, а если выполнить *.ToString()*, то уже непонятно как работать со строкой.

Comment: или уж просто удалить и заново добавить с обновленным значением?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается, нужно было всего лишь вставить Convert.ToInt32 в нужное место.

*DataGridView[x, y].Value = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView[x, y].Value) + 1;*